# Excel - return value if second character is number

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to return a value of zero if the second character in a string is numeric.

For example, `N227G6` - I want to look for the 2 as the second character and have a value of 0 returned.

I tried: `IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,2)),0,A1)`, but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: your use of "left" is incorrect as it returns the entire string after the '2' so basically "227G6". The MID is best suited here, since you only wish to match one character.

Comment: >IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A1,2,1)),A1,0)

Answer (score 5):

here another way

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,2,1)),0,A1)
```

Comment: This worked, can you explain why you need the -- before MID? Thank you :)

Comment: @MikeHill that translates a text number into an actual number. `ISNUMBER` only return TRUE if the value is an actual number, that said `ISNUMBER(2)` will return true but `ISNUMBER("2")` will return false, and `ISNUMBER(--"2")` will return true.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
IF(ISERROR(1*MID(A1,2,1)),A1,0)
```

Comment: Me neither - still returns the full string :/

Comment: Still returns the full string

Answer (score 3):

This is about the shortest I think:-

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,2,1)*0,A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 1 way to do it.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(MID(A1,2,1),"1234567890")), A1, 0)
```